# How to write hex FF symbols into file from CLOB-type field using UTL_FILE?

Tags: oracle, plsql, hex, clob, utl-file

Do anybody know how to insert into table with fields type «clob» a data which after using utl_file will look in the result file like  FF FF FF FF in hex-editor?
I did the next (and a lot of other attempts):

```
INSERT INTO DATA.FILE_TAB
(A1 --CLOB type field
)
select 
LPAD(chr(to_number('FF', 'XX')), 22, chr(to_number('FF', 'XX'))) A1
from DUAL;
```

after inserting I use  utl_file (put_line) to create a .dat file in the directory. When I open it, I saw anything but not needed chars. =( In hex-editor I need to see symbols FF FF FF FF FF FF like via the [link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/25164865/FF.png).

Comment: Run the following query: `SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS` and tell me what it returns for `PARAMETER_NAME = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET'` and `PARAMETER_NAME = 'NLS_SAVED_NCHAR_CS'`.

Comment: NLS_CHARACTERSET = AL32UTF8 and NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET = AL16UTF16

Comment: Note that if you change A1 to BLOB the following will work:  `INSERT INTO DATA.FILE_TAB(A1) VALUES (LPAD(HEXTORAW('FF'), 22, HEXTORAW('FF')))`.

Comment: LPAD(HEXTORAW('FF'), 22, HEXTORAW('FF')) doesn't work in my case (NLS_CHARACTERSET = AL32UTF8)

Comment: Given your character sets I'd expect this to work. I can't test it, though, as the databases I have available all use US7ASCII. It seems that you want to store binary data - could you convert A1 to be a BLOB instead of a CLOB?  Also, as I noted above, `LPAD(HEXTORAW('FF'), 22, HEXTORAW('FF'))` only works if A1 is a `BLOB`.

Comment: a cann't convert clob to blob because in this case i cann't conncatenate fields. i've tryied it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UTL_RAW](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_raw.htm#BABJHEGF) package for this purpose

```
insert into data.file_tab(a1)
values (lpad(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2('FF'), 22, utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2('FF')));
```

Comment: The results from your query appear to be dependent on the character set in use.  On our database, with NLS_CHARACTERSET = 'US7ASCII', I get '7F7F7F...' - i.e. the high-order bit gets truncated.